# clang - build with default flags

Tags: clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I want to use clang for cross compiling. I've found out that it seems very easy, I can specify architectures/includes etc. just as I invoke clang directly. 
 
 However, I don't want to keep passing those flags, I'd rather compile clang so that it would have these by default.
   That is, when I invoke clang just as `clang++ main.cpp` I'd like it to become `clang++ -i686-w64-mingw32 -target-isystem=/usr/some/path main.cpp` etc, how can I do that?

Comment: You can do that in several ways, such as using `makefile`, defining your `alias` in whatever shell you prefer, or you can write your own script file that gives the compiler the designated options for you. Maybe time for you to have some build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a response file to do this sort of thing, it's also how you'd avoid command lines that are too long for your OS.

Something like:

```
clang @target_cmds.inc -c foo.c
```

will likely work for you.

(In addition to the earlier comments of some build system hackery or an alias, you could also define clang as a wrapper script that you invoke that does the same thing, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/sh
clang -target i686-w64-mingw32 -target-isystem=/usr/some/path $@
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a makefile instead. Or create an alias in your bashrc. Everything else are crude hacks which I wouldn't use.